# Given a long string, find the matching strings in the dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, trie

Let's assume that we have a dictionary whose keys are the food names.

A user can input a food name string (i.e. "banana yogurt steak cheese cake"), and for the sake of simplicity, let's assume that everything is lower-case, and no food name appears more than once in the string.

What would be the most efficient way to find out what keys from the dictionary appeared in the food name string? Let's assume that it's possible that no key appears at all, and it's also possible that food name string only consists of the dictionary keys.

This is for self-study purpose. Use of **Suffix Trie** seems to be a good option, but I'm not sure how to optimize it (since there are possibly multiple matches in this case) If there are well-known theorems or references for it, i would really appreciate it.

PS. Thanks for the answer, but the only problem is that the **food name doesn't need to be one word long**. Let's think of something like this.

**"mild coffee ice cream"**

it's 4 word long string, but only 2 food names: **mild coffee, ice cream**

Comment: The keys of the dictionary are keys. What are the values? If they don't matter, do you really need a dictionary, or could it be a set?

Comment: @MAK values don't matter. it could be a set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) for that purpose:

```
set(food_string.split()) & food_dict.keys()
```

Note that `dict.keys()`, although not a `set`, supports the `set` API.

If no unambiguous boundary for food names can be identified (such as space ), then you can use the following:

```
[k for k in food_dict if k in food_string]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the only problem is that the food name doesn't need to be one word long. Let's think of something like this.

"mild coffee ice cream"

it's 4 word long string, but only 2 food names: mild coffee, ice cream

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you meant?

```
dict = {
  "banana": "answer1",
  "steak": "answer1",
  "cheese": "answer1"
}
input = "banana yogurt steak cheese cake"
for word in input.split():
    print (word)
    if word in dict:
        print ("true")
```

Output:

```
banana
true
yogurt
steak
true
cheese
true
cake
```

If it's not one word:

```
dict = {
  "banana milk shake": "answer1",
  "steak": "answer2",
  "ice cream": "answer3",
  "salad dressing": "answer4"
}
input = "banana milk shake yogurt steak cheese ice cream cake"
for key in dict:
    print (key)
    if key in input:
        print ("true")
    else:
        print ("false")
```

Output:

```
banana milk shake
true
steak
true
ice cream
true
salad dressing
false
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the only problem is that the food name doesn't need to be one word long. Let's think of something like this.

"mild coffee ice cream"

it's 4 word long string, but only 2 food names: mild coffee, ice cream

Comment: Somehow you need a reference. I'm assuming your keys are the correct values. Just go the other way around. If you still want to use method 1. Just form another list as reference. Check my edits.